# python multiprocessing shared variable safe

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm having troubles with the multiprocessing module. I have use the lock, but the below code is still not safe, I don't know why, the counter sometimes won't equal 100, how can I fix the code let it be safe?

```
import random
import threading
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

import time

lock = threading.Lock()


def a_complex_operation(counter):
    with lock:
        time.sleep(random.random())
        counter.value += 1


def main():
    pool = Pool(16)
    counter = Manager().Value('i', 0)

    for i in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(a_complex_operation, args=(counter,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    if counter.value != 100:
        print "not equal 100, current value is: "+str(counter.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0
    while True:
        t1 = time.time()
        main()
        count += 1
        print "the " + str(count) + " loop, cost time: " + str(time.time() - t1)
```

the output will be:

```
the 1 loop, cost time: 4.1369998455
the 2 loop, cost time: 3.74100017548
the 3 loop, cost time: 3.92299985886
the 4 loop, cost time: 4.05500006676
not equal 100, current value is: 99
the 5 loop, cost time: 4.01900005341
the 6 loop, cost time: 4.14299988747
```

then I test the Manager().list() and Manager().Value('i', 0) together

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import time


def a_complex_operation(list_, counter):
    for x in range(10):
        time.sleep(random.random()/10)
        list_.append(x)
        counter.value += 1


def main():
    pool = Pool(16)
    counter0 = 0
    list_ = Manager().list()
    counter = Manager().Value('i', 0)

    for i in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(a_complex_operation, args=(list_, counter))
        counter0 += 1

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    if len(list_) != 1000:
        print "length of list is not equal 1000, current is:" + str(len(list_))
    if counter.value != 1000:
        print "value of counter is not equal 1000, current is :" + str(counter.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = 0
    while True:
        counter += 1
        t1 = time.time()
        main()
        t2 = time.time()
        print "the " + str(counter) + " loop cost time: " + str(t2 - t1)
```

the output will be:

```
value of counter is not equal 1000, current is :916
the 1 loop cost time: 3.92299985886
value of counter is not equal 1000, current is :911
the 2 loop cost time: 3.98500013351
value of counter is not equal 1000, current is :925
the 3 loop cost time: 4.007999897
value of counter is not equal 1000, current is :913
the 4 loop cost time: 3.99399995804
value of counter is not equal 1000, current is :920
the 5 loop cost time: 4.09500002861
value of counter is not equal 1000, current is :915
```

I find Manager().list() is safe, Manager().Value('i', 0) is unsafe, interesting, anyone can tell me why Manager().list() looks like safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your subprocesses do not inherit the lock object. Or they do, but they are independent copies not linked together and cannot be used for anything. So there is a race condition and it eventually fails.

You can solve this by `Manager().Lock()` as you are already using Manager.

```
def a_complex_operation(counter, alock):
    with alock:
        time.sleep(random.random())
        counter.value += 1

def main():
    pool = Pool(16)
    ma = Manager()
    counter = ma.Value('i', 0)
    lock = ma.Lock()
    for i in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(a_complex_operation, args=(counter, lock))
```

This works (your subprocesses will now be much slower, though. Expect around 50 seconds per run, 100 times average 0.5 seconds).

But now your `counter.value` is always 100.

Comment: You can speed it up by putting `time.sleep(random.random())` outside "with" statement.

Comment: Of course.  I assume OP just uses sleep to simulate an operation that takes some amount of time.  My remark was only to remind of this. In the original message the code takes a couple of seconds per iteration as the lock does nothing and can always be acquired. In my solution lock works, but running time increases a lot, as it is supposed to.   (Initially when I tested it nothing happened in the first couple of seconds and I assumed there is a deadlock ... only to find out I was not patient enough)

Comment: it's not deadlock :)

Comment: No it is not. It works as expected. I was just impatient when I tried your code first and loops completed in a couple of seconds, and then when I fixed locking it took a long time. But this is the expected behaviour. Anyway, your locking problem seems to be solved with Manager.Lock().

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code should safe and fast, thanks @Hannu and @gzc

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import time


def a_complex_operation(list_, counter, lock):
    for x in range(10):
        time.sleep(random.random() / 10)
        with lock:
            list_.append(x)
            counter.value += 1


def main():
    pool = Pool(16)
    list_ = Manager().list()
    counter = Manager().Value('i', 0)
    lock = Manager().Lock()

    for i in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(a_complex_operation, args=(list_, counter, lock))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    if len(list_) != 1000:
        print ">>> length of list is not equal 1000, current is:" + str(len(list_))
    elif len(list_) == 1000:
        print ">>> length of list is equal 1000"
    if counter.value != 1000:
        print "value of counter is not equal 1000, current is :" + str(counter.value)
    elif counter.value == 1000:
        print "value of counter is equal 1000"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = 0
    while True:
        counter += 1
        t1 = time.time()
        main()
        t2 = time.time()
        print "the " + str(counter) + " loop cost time: " + str(t2 - t1)
        print "--------------------------------"
```

the output will be:

```
>>> length of list is equal 1000
value of counter is equal 1000
the 1 loop cost time: 3.78799986839
--------------------------------
>>> length of list is equal 1000
value of counter is equal 1000
the 2 loop cost time: 3.79299998283
--------------------------------
>>> length of list is equal 1000
value of counter is equal 1000
the 3 loop cost time: 3.78299999237
--------------------------------
>>> length of list is equal 1000
value of counter is equal 1000
the 4 loop cost time: 3.77500009537
--------------------------------
```